# Enhance Performance of mapview with 200+ markers

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, android-mapview

I am having 3 types of overlays on the map. 
1) there is one kind of overlays which is having simple markers. And on click of overlay i show pop up.
2) other kind of overlay contains canvas drawing. and onTouch event of these overlays we have to show third kind of overlay which contains bitmap drawing on the map. And click event of third kind of overlay is also there.

so, due to heavy  calculations and lots of canvas drawing, performance of mapview is degraded.

I have gone through Overlaymanager libreary from https://github.com/staroud-android/OverlayManager. but its not helping me.

Is there any way which can fulfill my requirements with high performance?

I also need suggestion that Polaris map library can help me for better performance? https://github.com/cyrilmottier/Polaris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that you are populating the `MapView` everytime you add a `GeoPoint`. Try adding this to your code:

after you have looped through the `GeoPoints` place this code

```
itemizedOverlay.populateNow();
```

and change you itemizedOverlay to look like this:

```
public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    m_overlays.add(overlay);
        }
public void populateNow()
{
    populate(); 
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return m_overlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return m_overlays.size();
}
```

Comment: thats ok (btw I'm using MapViewBallons in this example but should be along the same lines, that you only populate the mapview after all the geopoints have been added to the overlay)

Comment: i tried this. getting somewaht improved performance. but, for 3rd type of overlays. its behaving same. can u help me for that?

Comment: what is the third overlay doing?

Comment: in third obverlay draw method we have to draw bitmaps and some canvas drawing too